# How to show data from Access on C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I can write and add data on C# ( form application ) then I can't do that, I can't show the data from access to dataGridView1 on C#..

can sum1 help me for that ?

Comment: Try rewriting without the text-speak and I'll consider answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at

[Working with Data—Using the DataGridView](http://en.csharp-online.net/Working_with_Data%E2%80%94Using_the_DataGridView)

[C# Tutorial - Binding a DataGridView to a Database](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-binding-a-datagridview-to-a-database)

[Simple Movie Database in C# using Microsoft Access](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/simple_movie_database.aspx?msg=2493948)