# How to clear data from list view in c#

Tags: c#, .net, listview, datagridview

I have a button "Show data". When click it, data will display in list view. But I want to clear it and then click "Show data" again to display new data. Because I don't want when I click "Show data" again It duplicated data. So I want to clear old data to show new data (no duplicated data). But its header no clear (still keep header). What is the source code?

One more question. I want to show data from table in access to Datagridview in c# (eg. table in access contain: Name, Position, salary and Datagridview in c# has 3 column also: Name, Position and Salary by click on button "Show". What is the source code?

Answer (score 6):

In WinForms:

```
listView1.Clear();
```

In WPF:

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
```

Comment: but not headers in win form it clears header coloumn even only i have to clear row text

Answer (score 4):

for listView on clicking first clear the list and then add items: like below

```
    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Clear();
        listView1.Items.Add("Item1");
        listView1.Items.Add("Item2");
        listView1.Items.Add("Item3");
        listView1.Items.Add("Item4");
        listView1.Items.Add("Item5");
    }
```

for your second question try below link:

[How to show data from Access on C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694144/how-to-show-data-from-access-on-c)

Answer (score 1):

What about the following?

```
ListView lv = new ListView();
while (lv.Items.Count > 1) {
    //leave the header
    lv.Items.RemoveAt(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While making windows store app write:

```
listview.Items.Clear();
```

Just listview.Clear(); won't work in windows store app

Comment: I don't know why this answer was voted down, whereas it is exactly what he was asking for.
Clearing list without removing the header (or did I get it wrong?). Its just what I was looking for, too.
listView1.Clear(); 
clears the header as well!!
so one has to use
listview.Items.Clear();
and the header remains. Also in WinForms!!

Answer (score 1):

```
listView1.Items.Clear();
```

Clears in 2008 c# column headers with the data, if you have multiple ListView on the same form the best way is writing a method such as (suggested by Lasse as above)

```
private void ClearLvItems(ListView li)
{
   while(li.Items.Count>1)
      li.Items.RemoveAt(1); 
}
```

Or if it does not work as expected as it does not work with me (one row still rests in Listview)

```
 listView1.Items.Clear();
 SetHeaders(li); // If you have more then one ListView in the same form. Otherwise don't use the parameters.

 private void SetHeader(ListView li)
 {
   string[] header_names = new string[] {"Id","Name","SurName","Birth Date"};
    int i = 0;
    foreach (ColumnHeader ch in li.Columns) 
    {
        ch.Text = header_names[i];
        ++i;
    }
 }
```

Another discussion is
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4097986/2695927)

Answer (score 0):

[ListView.Clear Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.clear.aspx) removes all items and columns from the control.

The following are some articles that may help you working with [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) and [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) controls:

[ListView @ C# Online.Net](http://en.csharp-online.net/ListView)

[Working with Data—Using the DataGridView](http://en.csharp-online.net/Working_with_Data%E2%80%94Using_the_DataGridView)

Answer (score 0):

```
    foreach (ListView item in listview.Items)
    {
        ListView.Items.Remove(item);
    }
```

or

```
    ListView.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

put this at the **top** of your "Show Data" button's **click event**.

```
private void showData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // done
        {
             listViewData.Items.Clear();
             // your code
        }
```